# I had a trouble when i configure hadoop pseudodistributed mode

Tags: hadoop

i run this command: "% hdfs namenode -format", then run "start-dfs.sh --config $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop_pseudo",but it display following tips:

[Fatal Error] mapred-site.xml:25:1: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.(so much ...)

please tell me what's wrong with my command?

Comment: Sounds like your XML is misconfigured

Comment: can you paste the .XML content that you placed